# Python3 parse XML into dictionary

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

It seems the original post was too vague, so I'm narrowing down the focus of this post.  I have an XML file from which I want to pull values from specific branches, and I am having difficulty in understanding how to effectively navigate the XML paths.  Consider the XML file below.  There are several `<mi>` branches.  I want to store the `<r>` value of certain branches, but not others.  In this example, I want the `<r>` values of counter1 and counter3, but not counter2.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Data.xsl" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mdc SYSTEM "Data.dtd">
<mdc xmlns:HTML="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml">
<mfh>
<vn>TEST</vn>
<cbt>20140126234500.0+0000</cbt>
</mfh>
<mi>
    <mts>20140126235000.0+0000</mts>
    <mt>counter1</mt>
    <mv>
        <moid>DEFAULT</moid>
        <r>58</r>
    </mv>
</mi>
<mi>
    <mts>20140126235000.0+0000</mts>
    <mt>counter2</mt>
    <mv>
        <moid>DEFAULT</moid>
        <r>100</r>
    </mv>
</mi>
<mi>
    <mts>20140126235000.0+0000</mts>
    <mt>counter3</mt>
    <mv>
        <moid>DEFAULT</moid>
        <r>7</r>
    </mv>
</mi>
</mdc>
```

From that I would like to build a tuple with the following:
('20140126234500.0+0000', 58, 7)
where 20140126234500.0+0000 is taken from `<cbt>`, 58 is taken from the `<r>` value of the `<mi>` element that has `<mt>counter1</mt>` and 7 is taken from the `<mi>` element that has `<mt>counter3</mt>`.

I would like to use `xml.etree.cElementTree` since it seems to be standard and should be more than capable for my purposes.  But I am having difficulty in navigating the tree and extracting the values I need.  Below is some of what I have tried.

```
try:
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
except ImportError:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.ElementTree(file='Data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for mi in root.iter('mi'):
    print(mi.tag) 
    for mt in mi.findall("./mt") if mt.value == 'counter1':
        print(mi.find("./mv/r").value) #I know this is invalid syntax, but it's what I want to do :)
```

From a pseudo code standpoint, what I am wanting to do is:

```
find the <cbt> value and store it in the first position of the tuple.
find the <mi> element where <mt>counter1</mt> exists and store the <r> value in the second position of the tuple.
find the <mi> element where <mt>counter3</mt> exists and store the <r> value in the third position of the tuple.
```

I'm not clear when to use `element.iter()` or `element.findall()`.  Also, I'm not having the best of luck with using `XPath` within the functions, or being able to extract the info I'm needing.

Thanks,
Rusty

Comment: Post what you've tried. And BTW, regular `dict` is not ordered. Depending on your plotting software, you may want to maintain two parallel lists or maybe a list of tuples you use for sorting.

Comment: ...and how does one plot counter name anyway. Did you want the <r> value?

Comment: I've tried several things, but mostly I just don't even know how to go about it in Python.  I'll try to post some of what I've done so far.  And yes, I want to plot the r values.  And thanks for the suggestions for alternate approaches.  That's why I included the information about wanting to plot this.  I'm not sure if I'm going about it the right way with the dictionary.  If you could post some details about how to use the tuples, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I updated the post to narrow the focus and to incorporate the tuple instead of the dictionary as tdelaney suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET  # or with try/except as per your edit

xml_data1 = """<?xml version="1.0"?> and the rest of your XML here"""
tree = ET.fromstring(xml_data)  # or `ET.parse(<filename>)`
xml_dict = {}
```

Now `tree` has the xml tree and `xml_dict` will be the dictionary you're trying to get the result.

```
# first get the key & val for 'cbt'
cbt_val = tree.find('mfh').find('cbt').text
xml_dict['cbt'] = cbt_val
```

The counters are in `'mi'`:

```
for elem in tree.findall('mi'):
    counter_name = elem.find('mt').text            # key
    counter_val = elem.find('mv').find('r').text   # value
    xml_dict[counter_name] = counter_val
```

At this point, `xml_dict` is:

```
>>> xml_dict
{'counter2': '100', 'counter1': '58', 'cbt': '20140126234500.0+0000', 'counter3': '7'}
```

---

Some shortening, though possibly not as read-able: the code in the `for elem in tree.findall('mi'):` loop can be:

```
xml_dict[elem.find('mt').text] = elem.find('mv').find('r').text
# that combines the key/value extraction to one line
```

Or further, building the `xml_dict` can be done in just two lines with the counters first and `cbt` after:

```
xml_dict = {elem.find('mt').text: elem.find('mv').find('r').text for elem in tree.findall('mi')}
xml_dict['cbt'] = tree.find('mfh').find('cbt').text
```

---

*Edit:*

[From the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements), [`Element.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall) finds only elements with a tag which are direct children of the current element.

`find()` only finds the first direct child.

[`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter) iterates over all the elements recursively.

Comment: Thanks!  This looks very useful.  I'll test it shortly.

Comment: I had to change the for loop in your example to   `for elem in tree.find('md').findall('mi'):`  Otherwise, it would not find any elements.  Is that expected?  Is findall not recursive?  Edit - I see you actually answered that already.  It only finds direct children of the current element.

Comment: Can you recommend a good way to make it so that only certain counters are added to the dictionary?  For instance, only counter1 and counter3.  I realized the sample I provided didn't have the md tags which my original file had.

Comment: If your counters are called '_counter_' something, then before `xml_dict[counter_name] = counter_val` put `if counter_name.startswith('counter')`. Same for the 2-line version.